# React Native - how to control sound output in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, audio, text-to-speech

I have a problem with react-native-voice and react-native-tts, after interaction with user interface sound output has changed to the internal speaker and sound is very quiet. Maybe someone has the same problem and knows how to control sound output in iOS.

Thank you.

```
async _startRecognition(e) {
    if (Voice.isRecognizing()) return;

    this.resetSpeechState();
    try {
      await Voice.start('en-GB');
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  handleSpeak = (text) => {
    if (this.state.speaking) return false;

    Tts.getInitStatus().then(() => {
      Tts.speak(text);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the related code in your question?

Comment: @Raptor a second

Comment: @Raprot actually code doesn't matter in this case, coz we have a common problem with output control.

Answer (score -1):

> it's temporary solution until is it available in new `npm/yarn` release.

if you are using `react-native-voice` and `react-native-tts` both, then `react-native-voice` will create conflict. they have fixed this issue in their master branch, u have to take `Voice.m` from there and paste in your `node_module` package. 
First go to `react-native-voice` github, click the link below to see the `Voice.m` master branch code https://github.com/wenkesj/react-native-voice/blob/ae01a0876e2a9635ae4047dd230f5e7ef2d00672/ios/Voice/Voice.m
and copy whole code, then go to your node_nodules (node_modules/react-native-voice/ios/Voice/Voice.m) and replace the whole local code, save it. run your project, it should work now.

Comment: and after the next yarn install, you'll lose all your changes.

Comment: yes, that's the problem..
But  copying `Voice.m` will solve the issue again.
I know it's a temporary solution till it is available in new `npm/yarn` release.
 Something is better than nothing 